# Structure Learning Package for Bayes Net Toolbox MATLAB

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, bayesian-networks

I am reviewing [this MATLAB code](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/13562-structure-learning-package-for-bayes-net-toolbox),and  it have some examples, I am executing test_bnpc_asia.m, but get an error, How to correct it?
(I  have MATLAB R2010B)

executing:

```
>> test_bnpc_asia.m
================== phase I : 
Execution time : 0.12480

================== phase II : 
Execution time : 0.01560

================== phase III : 
Thinning - separateA
Thinning - separateB
Thinning - orient_edges
Infering directions 0 boucles
Execution time : 0.10920

score_Phase_3 =

 -6.0994e+003

Report genered in :

ans =

C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2010b\BNT_SLP\examples

Warning: Direct access of structure fields returned by a function call (e.g.,
 call to test_bnpc_asia) is not allowed. See MATLAB 7.10 Release Notes, "Subscripting Into Function Return Values" for details. 
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just type

```
test_bnpc_asia
```

instead of

```
test_bnpc_asia.m
```

The file extension is added automatically. If you add it, MATLAB thinks that the function test_bnpc_asia returns a structure and you want to access the field "m" contained in that structure.